# Create Folder in Informatica using Pmrep

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I am trying to create folder in Informatica using PMREP command. 
Syntax below.

Can i call this command (pmrep) directly from command task or I have to put this command in Shell script and call this shell script in command task?

Also, I do not see any option to pass user credentials in this command, will it automatically take these details from the parent workflow where I add this in command task?

pmrep createFolder -n  [-d folder_description] [-o owner_name] [-a owner_security_domain] [-s shared_folder] [-p permissions] [-f active | frozendeploy | frozennodeploy]

Answer (score 0):

Above pmrep command is to create a folder in Informatica repository which would be one time creation. There is no point in creating it through command task, because when you execute the workflow multiple times, command task tries to create the folder multiple times in Informatica repository which leads to the failure of the workflows. If you are creating a folder in Informatica repository, create it through terminal.

If you are creating folder in the server use below command in command task,

`mkdir folder_name`

Please mention if it's for Informatica repository folder or a directory in your machine, so that can help you according to your requirement.